# R execude expression on warning/error

Tags: r, warnings

I process huge data sets and therefore my R program runs for several hours. Sometimes it happens that something goes wrong and the program aborts with some warning/error message. Most times this are not the warning messages I programmed myself because I thought on what could go wrong - it is something unexpected causing an warning or error in some base R function I call. For the warning messages I programmed myself I could use the `expr` argument of `warning`. Is there something similar as a global option?

R (I am using Rstudio on Win 8) is only running in the background, as I have other work to do. From time to time I tap to R to see if it is still running. 
In case if something goes wrong I want to raise a beep sound like `beep(sound=1)` from the [beepr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/beepr/index.html) package.

Is there any way to execude some expression (like this `beep(sound=1)`) when a warning/error is raised? It suffices the latter as one can promote every warning to an error by `options(warn=2)` and it might be hard to execute some expression if R still executes some other expression which threw the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tryCatch` to do that in the following way:

**Example that produces a warning:**

```
x <- 1:10
y <- if (x < 5 ) 0 else 1

Warning message:
In if (x < 5) 0 else 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

**Using tryCatch**

```
>tryCatch(if (x < 5 ) 0 else 1, 
          warning = function(x) print(x),
          finally = print('hello'))

<simpleWarning in if (x < 5) 0 else 1: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used>
[1] "hello"
```

In the code above where I have `print(hello)` add `beep(sound=1)` and it will give you a beep sound whenever it gives a warning.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I just use `tryCatch(eval(expr), finally=beep(sound=1))`.
Is there a way to invoke tryCatch globaly? Or do I have to wrap it around my code every time I want to use it?

Comment: Well, you can wrap it around any code that you think might produce a warning or you can wrap it around your whole script (have never used it for a huge script though)

Comment: I mean I use `tryCatch(eval(expr), warning=warning, finally=beep(sound=1))`, i.e. `warning=function(x) {warning(x)}` in your answer. I forgot the most important part in my previous comment.